# Handling JSON in PHP as a String

Tags: php, json, jquery-ui

Student here. For a project, I implemented [jQuery UI's autocomplete widget](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote). The widget allows a call to a PHP script which returns JSON data containing the suggestions. The API I was interfacing with provided a large JSON file of allowed entries (something like 30 megs) in the form:

```
[
  {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  },
```

You get the idea. To find partial matches, here is the PHP script I wrote:

```
<?php

$cityPage = file_get_contents("citylist.json");

function strpos_all($haystack, $needle) {
    $offset = 0;
    $cityArray = array();
    while (($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset)) !== FALSE) {
        $offset   = $pos + 1;
        $length= (strpos($haystack, '"coord"', $offset)-$pos);
        $city = str_replace('",
    "country": "',", ",(substr($haystack, $pos, ($length-7))));
        if (in_array($city,$cityArray) == FALSE) {
          $cityArray[] = $city;
        }
    }
    return $cityArray;
}
echo json_encode(strpos_all($cityPage, $_GET['term']));
?>
```

I had originally tried to use json_decode after file_get_contents but figured that really was an unnecessary performance hit since 1) the JSON file is so large and 2) I don't really care if it's a JSON object (is that the right terminology?) in PHP, I can just as easily deal with it as a string.

So three questions:

1. Do you agree with just leaving it as a string?
2. As you can see when I set my $city variable (to remove all of the stuff in the middle- I really just wanted everything in the format "London, UK"), the line spacing/white spacing gets weird. Is there a better way to handle this?
3. Related to #2 above. As you can see in my substr function, I had to subtract 7 from my calculated length to get the desired output (I basically did this by adjusting fire and walking it in until I got the desired output). How would I know this/better calculate it in the future?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) NO 2) yes leave it as JSON 3) no idea I am afraid

Comment: Whatever that code does (→ not very readable) it would definitely be simpler with a regex. And if you're just looking for city names, simply preconvert the JSON to a `cities.json`; and use that.

Comment: If I may expand on @RiggsFolly's response to point 1: *good god NO.*

Comment: Put it in a database, even sqlite. If citylist.json updates often then use a cronjob to insert new entries.

Comment: For #3, how long is your "needle" in other words how long is this `"coord"`  I'm just guessing here, but it's not unlikely you have to offset the length of that.  (including the quotes `'"coord"'` as its double quoted)  For #1,  No, for number #2,  pull the data with a query which improves as they they type, with about a 1/2 second delay.  Basically if they stop typing for 1/2 second send the AJAX. Query the DB and give them X number of results.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you agree with just leaving it as a string?

Not usually, might be helpful if you're looking for one specific string.

> As you can see when I set my `$city` variable (to remove all of the stuff in the middle- I really just wanted everything in the format "London, UK"), the line spacing/white spacing gets weird. Is there a better way to handle this?

Since you're looking for just one portion of the JSON data, I would strongly advise moving it to an SQL Database. If it must remain as a JSON file and you're expecting sizes of 30 MB or more, then chunking it might be the way to go.

```
$c = 1; // Skip first "["
$len = 256; // Read a chunk of 256 characters
$cityArr = array();
for($c; $c > 0; $c+=$len){
  $chunk = file_get_contents("citylist.json", FALSE, NULL, $c, $len);
  $nextChar = file_get_contents("citylist.json", FALSE, NULL, $c+$len, 1);
  $obj = json_decode($chunk);
  array_push($cityArr, $obj['country']);
  if($nextChar == "]"){
    $c = -1;
  }
}
echo json_encode($cityArr);
```

This is hap-hazard at best since there is no way to know how many characters need to be read to get to the end of the Object statement. The alternative is to read line by line and look for `{` and `}` in the line.

Another option is here: https://github.com/shevron/ext-jsonreader This is designed to handle large streams of JSON data.

> Related to #2 above. As you can see in my `substr()`, I had to subtract 7 from my calculated length to get the desired output (I basically did this by adjusting fire and walking it in until I got the desired output). How would I know this/better calculate it in the future?

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

> If `start` is non-negative, the returned string will start at the start'th position in string, counting from zero. For instance, in the string 'abcdef', the character at position 0 is 'a', the character at position 2 is 'c', and so forth.
>
> If `start` is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string.

So you could do this:

```
$city = str_replace('",\r\n\t"country": "',", ",(substr($haystack, $pos, -7)));
```

Then again, you might consider using a regular expression to capture just that specific line. We know some consistent things about our strings that we want, we want these specific strings:

```
\t"country": "UA",\r\n
\t"country": "RU",\r\n
```

If we consider that JSON does not need to conform to any specific formatting, we can look for this with something like:

```
/\"country\":\s\"(?P<country>.*)\",/g
```

Hence, if you're searching for just these values from the file, you could just read it line by line and search for matches to this pattern.

```
<?php
$cityArr = array();
$fh = fopen("citylist.json", "r");
while (!feof($fh)) {
  $line = fgets($file_handle);
  preg_match('/\"country\":\s\"(?P<country>.*)\",/', $line, $matches);
  array_push($cityArr, $matches['country']);
}
fclose($file_handle);
echo json_encode($cityArr);
?>
```

This would result in:

```
[
  "UA",
  "RU",
  ....
]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A way to go is to ensure that the JSON suggestion fetched has been parsed to an array using the `json_decode` method. Loop through this array and check the `query string` against the `name` and `country` attributes of each object on each loop, then for those that match, construct the suggestion string and push into the `$cityArray`.

But owing to the fact that the size of the `JSON` suggestion data might be so large, this logic might have negative effect on the performance of the script.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's exactly what I was aiming for originally with json_decode but I kept bumping up against "Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted". I upped my memory_limit in my .ini but then I started to run into performance issues. I'm thinking also maybe just caching the output of json_decode might help in the future so that at least it would only be a problem for the first user. Thoughts?

Comment: @StudentDeveloper7 You can setup `file_get_contents()` in a chunk sense. Make use of the `offset` and `maxlen` to grab chunks at a time. Then you can just parse those chunks, gathering the details you need. This will reduce your memory overhead yet make more work. Do some testing to see how much data you get, and then you could read in just each `{  ... }` element from the array via chunks.

Comment: The 30meg json file is your base problem. Is this a file in lieu of a database, or is it data that you strip from a database to pass to a js script? Either way its way to large for a json file/ data structure. I think you may need to re-engineer the whole process..